# percentile_approx in hive returning zero

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have been trying to check the percentile_approx for a set of users. The intention behind this is to get the top 25% of customers in the data set. So, in order to check that, I ran the following HIVE query.

```
select percentile_approx(amount, 0.75)
from sales
```

However, the value returned from this query is `0.0`.  I am not sure what the problem is. When I run this query over a sample of few records the result is what is expected.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Note - I am trying to find the percentile in a data set containing more than 3.3 M records.

Comment: maybe try sample first? something like:

`select percentile_approx(amount, 0.75)
from sales tablesample(0.01 percent)`

Answer (score -1):

```
select percentile_approx(cast(amount as double), ARRAY(0.75))
from sales
```

Try this method

Comment: We can see what you've changed - but it's always useful to explain why your changes may fix the OP's issue.

Answer (score -1):

Generally percentile_approx() works on integer type data. Please make sure that you have applied this on the column which has integers.

Comment: percentile_approx() works on floating points. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inFunctions